# Hyperref Package Doesn't Make Colored Borders

Tags: hyperref

I'm writing latex code with overleaf and I want to make hyperlinks with the hyperref packages. From Googling, I learned that by default (or setting colorlinks=false) should make borders around the links. However, this doesn't work for me. Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[colorlinks=false]{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\title{Test}

\begin{document}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\begin{theorem} \label{theorem1}
Famous theorem
\end{theorem}

\newpage

Using Theorem \ref{theorem1}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Strange, I do see a red border with my pdf viewer (okular) in the "using theorem 1" sentence. Do you have a recent tex distribution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It fully depends on the PDF viewer you are using. Some viewers show this border while some others don't.

This is when your document was viewed using Adobe Acrobat Reader and the box was visible.
[image: Adobe]

And this is when your document was viewed using the Brave browser and the box disappeared.
[image: Brave]

Also, if you print your document, this box won't get printed. If you want to highlight a link, I think it's better to use color or underline or both.

Comment: About the final remark: I always considered that the box doesn't get printed the biggest advantage of using these boxes. Marked links in printed documents always feels odd IMO since you can't actually click them, so the fact that they used to be links feels rather irrelevant.

Comment: @MarcelKrüger Yes, I also agree that highlighted links in the printed document are of no use. However, I don't like these red boxes, so I usually hide these boxes and instead highlight the links.